# How to mimic RC signals using raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, hardware, arduino, remote

I am working on an automated Quadcopter and I am trying to build a flight controller using Arduino board and raspberry pi.
I don't want to use a transmitter and receiver in this project instead wants to use raspberry pi to send RC like signals to Arduino just like we connect raspberry pi to traditional flight controllers like PixiHawk and KK 2.1.

Like raspberry pi will be connected to Arduino using gpio pins and there will be a script running on raspberry pi which will send RC signals for roll,pitch,yaw and throttle to Arduino.
and I can control these values using keyboard.

I am using [this](http://www.brokking.net/ymfc-al_main.html) project for flight controller software.

Now my question is, is there any method to build something like this??

Comment: What is a "RC signal"?

Comment: What are you planning on using for a transmitter and receiver. The Pi to the best of my knowledge cannot generate an RF signal it the appropriate band for remote control, however the units shown in your link will give you 4 channels. It will be an interesting design problem figuring out how to get the need lift and battery life.  If you do it wired it should become fairly straightforward.

Comment: Welcome.  Referring to signals you are sending over a wire to an Arduino as "RC" is confusing -- they are not "radio control" because it isn't radio.   You should edit your question to clarify this rather than having to say "I don't want to use a transmitter" etc.